# Webpack load image inside of HTML

Tags: javascript, html, image, webpack

Somewhere in the middle of my Angular template I have img tag:

```
<img src="../../images/error.gif" />
```

Until now I was using `raw-loader` with this simple configuration:

```
   test: /\.html/,
   loader: 'raw'
```

But after i read this i decide I need a change:

> The raw-loader is supposed to turn a text file into a CommonJS module
>   that exports the file contents as a string – nothing more.

**What did I change:**

So I changed my raw-loader to html-loader based on [this article](http://blog.andrewray.me/webpack-when-to-use-and-why/) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400733/webpack-and-angular-html-image-loading).

```
    {
    test: /\.html$/,
    loader: [
        "html?" + JSON.stringify({
            attrs: ["img:src", "img:ng-src"]
        })
     ]
    }
```

And this: loader

```
{ test: /.gif$/, loader: "file" }
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30485183/webpack-require-relative-image) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33243399/webpack-outputs-wrong-path-for-images) questions I added `publicPath: "/assets"` to my webpackconfig. 
And changed `img` tag on `<img src=" { require('/assets/logo.png') }  " />`

**My webpackconfig looks like:**

```
webpack({
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './main.js'),
        output: {
            path: dir_dist,
            filename: 'custom-shared-lib.js',
            publicPath: "/assets"
        },
    module: {
        preLoaders: [
            {
                test: dir_bin,
                loader: path.resolve(__dirname, "./my-loader.js"),
                query: JSON.stringify(preLoaderQuery)
            },
        ],
        loaders: loader
    },
    plugins: [
        // Avoid publishing files when compilation fails
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ],
}, function(err, stats) {
    console.log(stats.toString());
});
```

While variabile loaders are:

```
[
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: [dir_bin, dir_src],
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
            presets: ['es2015']
        }
    },
    {
       test: /\.html$/,
       loader: [
        "html?" + JSON.stringify({
            attrs: ["img:src", "img:ng-src"]
        })
      ]
    },
    { test: /.gif$/, loader: "file" }
]
```

**Error:**

This error happen while compiling:

> Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./ {
>   require('/assets/error.gif') }

I would be happy for any advice.